# Align buttons at the bottom of rows of divs within a div container

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with rows of 'cards' which each contain an img, some text below, and an  link styled as a button. The text varies in length but I want each card to be of equal length and the buttons to be aligned toward the bottom of each card.

```
<!--Grid row-->
<div class="row">
    <!--Grid column-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-4">
        <!--Card-->
        <div class="card">
            <!--Card image-->
            <div class="view overlay">
                <img src="img/bb/didyouknow.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <a href="didyouknow.html" onclick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Did You Know'); return false;">
                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--Card content-->
            <div class="card-body">
                <!--Title-->
                <h4 class="card-title">Did you know?</h4>
                <!--Text-->
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="didyouknow.html" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Did You Know'); return false;">More</a>
                <!--<button id="didyouknow" type="button" onclick="window.open('didyouknow.html','_self'); trackOutboundLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Did You Know'); return false;" class="btn btn-primary">More</button>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Card-->
    </div>
    <!--Grid column-->
    <!--Grid column-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <!--Card-->
        <div class="card">
            <!--Card image-->
            <div class="view overlay">
                <img src="img/bb/tipsntricks.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <a href="staysmokefree.html" onclick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Stay Smoke Free'); return false;">
                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--Card content-->
            <div class="card-body">
                <!--Title-->
                <h4 class="card-title">Stay smoke free</h4>
                <!--Text-->
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Lots of text. Lots of text. Lots of text. Lots of text. Lots of text.</p>
                <a href="staysmokefree.html" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Stay Smoke Free'); return false;">More</a>
                <!--<button type="button" onclick="window.open('staysmokefree.html','_self');" class="btn btn-primary">More</button>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Card-->
    </div>
    <!--Grid column-->
</div>
<!--Grid row-->
```

This CSS makes each card the same height by making the cards height fill the parent div:

```
.row {
    display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
    position:relative;
}

.card{
    height: 100%;/* fill parent div height*/
}
```

The problem I have is that the buttons are not horizontally aligned because they just sit below where the text finishes. If I do this:

```
.card-body a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

the buttons are aligned at the bottom of the cards but they overlap and cover the text. How can I get the buttons to appear below the text and align across cards?

EDIT: I've made a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/captncanary/m156dqeu/

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's actually really quite difficult as I'm using bootstrap and can't include all the files and don't know which pieces I need to provide. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  }
  
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  
  h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
      max-width: 960px;
    }
  }
  
  .container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  .row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  
  
  .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col,
  .col-auto, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm,
  .col-sm-auto, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md,
  .col-md-auto, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg,
  .col-lg-auto, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl,
  .col-xl-auto {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  
  
    .col-md-4 {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
      flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
      max-width: 33.333333%;
    }
    .col-md-6 {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
      flex: 0 0 50%;
      max-width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-8 {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
      flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
      max-width: 66.666667%;
    }
    .col-md-12 {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  
    .col-lg-3 {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
      flex: 0 0 25%;
      max-width: 25%;
    }
  
  .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
  }
  
  .card {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  
  .card-body {
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
  }
  
  /* make cards on index page equal size and align buttons*/
  .row {
      display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
      position:relative;
  }
  
  .card{
      height: 100%;/* fill parent div height*/
  }
  
  .card-body a {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Demo</title>
       <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!--Main Navigation-->
    <header>
    </header>
    <!--Main Navigation-->
    <!--Main layout-->
    <main class="mt-5">
        <!--Main container-->
        <div id="maincontainer" class="container">


            <!--Grid row-->
            <div class="row">

                <!--Grid column-->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-4">

                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card">

                        <!--Card image-->
                        <div class="view overlay">
                            <img src="img/bb/didyouknow.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <a href="didyouknow.html" onclick="trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Did You Know'); return false;">
                                <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">Did you know?</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="didyouknow.html" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Did You Know'); return false;">More</a>
                            <!--<button id="didyouknow" type="button" onclick="window.open('didyouknow.html','_self'); trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Did You Know'); return false;" class="btn btn-primary">More</button>-->

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->

                </div>
                <!--Grid column-->
                <!--Grid column-->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card">

                        <!--Card image-->
                        <div class="view overlay">
                            <img src="img/bb/tipsntricks.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <a href="ssf.html" onclick="trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'SSF'); return false;">
                                <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">Stay smoke free</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="ssf.html" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'SSF'); return false;">More</a>
                            <!--<button type="button" onclick="window.open('staysmokefree.html','_self');" class="btn btn-primary">More</button>-->
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->

                </div>
                <!--Grid column-->
                <!--Grid column-->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card">

                        <!--Card image-->
                        <div class="view overlay">
                            <img src="img/bb/htl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <a href="timeline.html" onclick="trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Timeline'); return false;">
                                <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">Timeline</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="timeline.html" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Timeline'); return false;">More</a>
                            <!--<button type="button" onclick="window.open('timeline.html','_self');" class="btn btn-primary">More</button>-->
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->

                </div>
                <!--Grid column-->
                <!--Grid column-->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-4">

                    <!--Card-->
                    <div class="card">

                        <!--Card image-->
                        <div class="view overlay">
                            <img src="img/bb/yoursavings.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <a href="savings.html" onclick="trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Your Savings'); return false";>
                                <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <!--Card content-->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <h4 class="card-title">Your Savings</h4>
                            <!--Text-->
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="savings.html" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="trackClickedLink(this, 'Internal Links', 'Your Savings'); return false;">More</a>
                            <!--<button type="button" onclick="window.open('savings.html','_self');" class="btn btn-primary">More</button>-->
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->

                </div>
                <!--Grid column-->

            </div>
            <!--Grid row-->
            
        </div>
        <!--Main container-->
    </main>
    <!--Main layout-->
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer class="page-footer text-center text-md-left font-small pt-4 mt-4">
    </footer>
    <!--/.Footer-->
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you just change absolute to relative? That alone doesn't work for me. I've made a jsfiddle now to help.

Comment: plz rerun code snippet .card-body a {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
  }

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I needed to achieve the same layout and the solution that worked the best for me was to use **flexbox**.

Basically, I needed to separate the Upper content from my "footer content" and then set `justify-content: space-between;` to the body.

[image]

[Here, is a working example in JSFiddle of what I tried to explain](https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigofepy/a931ex8o/).

**Summarizing the changes:**

- Wrap your upper content such as the title and description inside a `<div class="card-content">`, the button should be outside of this element.
- Set the following styles to `.card-body`:

`CSS`

```
.card-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}
```

- Set `align-self: flex-start;` to the button to preserve its width.

I hope it helps

Comment: That's pretty good. I had to remove height: 100%; to remove some problems with spacing. It would be a bit better if the small text was also aligned across columns. Could you help with that too please?